# What JavaScript functions exist that I can use to check that an email and phone # are valid without resorting to a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

On a form, I need to make sure that all fields are filled in and that the phone # and email address are valid.  I tried using a jQuery validation plugin but it changed the page's look and feel. The plugin also was dynamically looking for some css files in some spot that was unexpected.

I love jQuery but the plugin seemed too much for what I wanted.

Since all I need to do is to make sure the fields are not empty and that the phone number is valid and email is valid, what javascript functions do you suggest? I will still use jQuery core.

Serverside we want to use apache commons PhoneNumberFormatter and same with email validation.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I am OK with using jQuery. I just did not want to use a plugin which would change the page's look by inserting error messages where it wants and cost too much time/money in learning how to use it and install it properly.

Comment: I also want the validation to happen on form submission in order to provide the same kind of user experience they had on the previous page.

Comment: If this is for a public website be sure your solution allows for foreign phone numbers which (a) won't necessarily follow the format of whatever country you're in, and (b) may be entered with a '+' at the beginning with the country code, e.g., +61 for Australia.

Comment: That's a good point.  In this case, the scope is limited to USA and Canada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [JavaScript regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html), using the RegExp object that comes as a standard part of JavaScript. You can use that to perform basic checking of [email addresses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) and phone numbers.

e.g.

```
function emailIsValid(emailAddress) {
  var emailRegex = /\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/;
  return !!emailAddress.match(emailRegex);
}
```

The code above is not tested, but it should give you an idea of how to do it. Just do the same again for the telephone number, and then do something like this:

```
if (emailIsValid(emailAddressValue) && telephoneNumberIsValid(telephoneValue)) {
  //Submit form
} else {
  alert ("There are errors on the form, please correct and invalid data");
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that if you want to _properly_ validate email addresses with a regular expression, then you have to use this one: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html . You have to strip any comments and replace them with whitespace, though, so even then regexes aren't entirely sufficient.

Comment: ... now that is a monster of a regex.

Comment: In Java, apache commons came up with an email validator class that many use. Isn't there something like that in javascript that many use and is considered safe and good?

Comment: @finneycanhelp - Aside from a regex, not that I'm aware of. Regular expressions are pretty much the de-facto standard for validating email addresses on client side. If you need anything more complex, I'd recommend doing it server side, since in the end all a user has to do is disable JavaScript in their browser and all your work is undone.

Answer (score 2):

In [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/9ssKZ/) you'll find a JQueryless method I use to check form fields. It checks all form fields periodically using an interval function.

Comment: Why on EARTH do you use interval for checking fields? Why not onchange or onkeydown or onanything for that matter. You just wast a hellova lot of cpu-cycles.

Comment: Because there are other ways to change a field that do not trigger key events, and onchange only triggers on blur, not straight away. If you want to catch *all* changes as they happen, you have no choice but to use an interval (possibly backed by key events and onchange as well). HTML5's `input` event will eventually make this approach redundant.

Comment: Because someone asked me ;). The cpu doesn't seem to be bothered (1% load every 5-10 seconds) and it's one of many ways to validate. Sorry it didn't fit into your thinking frame.

Comment: @bobince: thanks. HTML5 should be standard around 2014, I read somewhere, w3c did a last call for review (http://www.w3.org/2011/05/html5lc-pr.html). 
@Alxandr: input could be coming from a barcode reader for example.

Comment: Holy crap... I can't believe I'm actually agreeing with this... And it doesn't clog up the other scripts on the page?

Comment: @Alxandr: it doesn't, at least I have never experienced clog ups from `setInterval`. Actually (I'm not sure of this), aren't regular event listeners a kind of intervalled functions?

Comment: Thei're not intervalls, more like timeouts, I'd say. Cause it's not like it happens on scedule xD

Comment: @Alxndr: http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/e60b8be7a97b/content/events/src/nsEventStateManager.cpp contains code for event listeners. C++ It's not my language, so I can't tell more.

Comment: @Kooilnc @Alxandr @bobince Fascinating! I had not considered these scenarios. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Everyone focused on the email and phone number validation, but encase you need help with detecting empty text boxes and even just how/when to call the code for email/phone validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    var curVal;
    for(var index = 1 ; index < 15 ; index++)
    {
        curVal = document.getElementById("textbox_"+index).value
        if(curVal == "")
        {
            alert("empty text box")
            return(false); //false will stop the form from submitting
        }
        if(index = 5)// email text box
        {
            //validate email
        }
    }
}
</script>
<type="input" id="textbox_1">
<type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="validate()">
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one for email

```
function checkemail()
{
    var str=email
    var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]  {2})?)$/i
    if (filter.test(str))
    testresults=true
     else
     {
       alert("Please input a valid email address!")
       testresults=false
     }
```

Comment: Nice!  http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html helped.  I see ok@10.0.0.1 does not work. Should it matter?